# Time complexity to compute f(k).

Tags: number-theory, computational-complexity, elliptic-curves, cryptography

Suppose that $f(x)$ is polynomial, over finite field, of degree $n$. What is the time complexity to compute $f(k)$ for a given $k$?

It would be a great help!

Thank you.

Comment: Time complexity comes from computing algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By [Horner's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method), at most $O(n)$ multiplications need to be performed. Based on [the recent breakthrough](https://www.texmacs.org/joris/ffnlogn/ffnlogn-abs.html), each multiplication takes time at most $O(\log q\log\log q)$ (under some plausible number theoretical assumption). Since the time needed for additions is dominated by multiplications, the complexity can be made $O(n\log q \log\log q)$ for $k\simeq\mathbb F_q$. (Note that $\log q$ is the number of bits needed to encode elements of $\mathbb F_q$.)

Comment: Might be too optimistic, because techniques like FFT/Schönhage-Strassen only play out for really big numbers, like with 10000 digits or so.

Comment: @Just a user Thank you!